# Auto restart Ionic / Cordova App after crash

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am currently building an app (both Android & iOS) which requires to be running until users exits the app. The expectation is also to survive app crash.

I am using Ionic for the same. Is there a way in Android and iOS to restart the app immediately after crash?

Comment: sounds like you'll need to be saving app state frequently. Take a look at this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031153/ionic-hybrid-app-saving-application-state-data-on-exit

Comment: Thanks, that was useful. I will try it out tonight. However, is there event that would be fired when the app crashes. This is the specific scenario I need to handle.